# how to create context menu in RecyclerView using addOnItemTouchListener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, contextmenu, android-contextmenu

how to create context menu in `RecyclerView` using `addOnItemTouchListener` when user long click?

I have code like this

```
public class AllDataFragment extends Fragment{

    List<GetDataAdapterRiwayat> GetDataAdapter1;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerViewlayoutManager;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewadapterRiwayat;

    String FIXURL = "http://192.168.43.139/AndroidFileUpload/";
    String GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL = FIXURL+"GetAllData.php";
    String JSON_ID_TEMPAT_PERCETAKAN = "id_tempat_percetakan";
    String JSON_NAMA_PERCETAKAN = "nama_percetakan";
    String JSON_LATITUDE = "latitude";
    String JSON_LONGITUDE = "longitude";
    String JSON_GAMBAR = "gambar";
    String JSON_STATUS = "status";
    String JSON_EMAIL1 = "email1";
    String JSON_EMAIL2 = "email2";
    String JSON_EMAIL3 = "email3";
    SessionManager session;
    RequestQueue requestQueue ;
    String email;

    public AllDataFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        GetDataAdapter1 = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.recyclerview2);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        recyclerViewlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewlayoutManager);
        JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL();
        Log.d(TAG, "acoba nih1 : ");
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                GetDataAdapterRiwayat GetDataAdapterRiwayat = GetDataAdapter1.get(position);
                Log.d(TAG, "acoba nih3 : ");
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailRiwayatActivity.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("Gambar",GetDataAdapterRiwayat.getGambar());// getDataAdapter1 in your case
                myIntent.putExtra("IdTempatPercetakan",GetDataAdapterRiwayat.getIdTempatPercetakan());// getDataAdapter1 in your case
                myIntent.putExtra("NamaPercetakan",GetDataAdapterRiwayat.getNamaPercetakan());// getDataAdapter1 in your case
                myIntent.putExtra("Latitude",GetDataAdapterRiwayat.getLatitude());// getDataAdapter1 in your case
                myIntent.putExtra("Longitude",GetDataAdapterRiwayat.getLongitude());// getDataAdapter1 in your case
                myIntent.putExtra("Status",GetDataAdapterRiwayat.getStatus());// getDataAdapter1 in your case
                myIntent.putExtra("Email1",GetDataAdapterRiwayat.getEmail1());// getDataAdapter1 in your case
                myIntent.putExtra("Email2",GetDataAdapterRiwayat.getEmail2());// getDataAdapter1 in your case
                myIntent.putExtra("Email3",GetDataAdapterRiwayat.getEmail3());// getDataAdapter1 in your case
                startActivity(myIntent);

            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        // Menu Item Clicked!
        return true;
    }

    public void JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL() {
        setSessionManager();
        CustomJsonArrayRequest request = new CustomJsonArrayRequest (GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL  + "?&email="+email,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }

    public void JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(JSONArray array){
        for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {

            GetDataAdapterRiwayat GetDataAdapter2 = new GetDataAdapterRiwayat();

            JSONObject json = null;
            try {

                json = array.getJSONObject(i);
                GetDataAdapter2.setIdTempatPercetakan(json.getString(JSON_ID_TEMPAT_PERCETAKAN));
                GetDataAdapter2.setNamaPercetakan(json.getString(JSON_NAMA_PERCETAKAN));
                GetDataAdapter2.setLatitude(json.getString(JSON_LATITUDE));
                GetDataAdapter2.setLongitude(json.getString(JSON_LONGITUDE));
                GetDataAdapter2.setGambar(json.getString(JSON_GAMBAR));
                GetDataAdapter2.setStatus(json.getString(JSON_STATUS));
                GetDataAdapter2.setEmail1(json.getString(JSON_EMAIL1));
                GetDataAdapter2.setEmail2(json.getString(JSON_EMAIL2));
                GetDataAdapter2.setEmail3(json.getString(JSON_EMAIL3));
            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            GetDataAdapter1.add(GetDataAdapter2);
        }

        recyclerViewadapterRiwayat = new RecyclerViewAdapterRiwayat(GetDataAdapter1, getActivity());

        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapterRiwayat);
    }

    private void setSessionManager() {
        session = new SessionManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        session.checkLogin();

        // get user data from session
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
        // email
        email = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_EMAILUSER);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_all_data, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }

}
```

Comment: You need to register the recycler for contextmenus in the host activity, then call showContextMenu (on your viewholder itemview) in your long click.

Comment: @SaikCaskey how to register that?

Comment: call the function registerForContextMenu in your activity (here's [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#registerForContextMenu(android.view.View)) - it's an Activity function

Comment: i.e., Context.this.registerForContextMenu(mRecyclerView); you can actually do it in a fragment as well

Comment: @EggySudianto Try the answer posted below

Comment: @SaikCaskey sorry I can't understand, I write my full code maybe it can help to hel me fix it

Comment: OP doesn't sound like he knew what he wanted- would just like to note that there's a clear distinction between a ContextMenu and a contextual menu for a view item. One appears anchored to a view (think songs in Play Music app), the other appears in the middle of the screen with everything else greyed out

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

Note: Make sure you add this to adapter class.

Add an `ImageButton` inside RecyclerView Adapter layout with some id like .. 
`ivOverflowIcon`.

Inside Adapter Class.

```
ImageButton buttonViewOption;
```

Inside `ViewHolder(View v)`

```
buttonViewOption= (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.ivOverflowIcon);
```

Add this to menu:
**res/menu/mycontextmenu.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu1"
        android:title="Menu 1" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu2"
        android:title="Menu 2" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu3"
        android:title="Menu 3" />


</menu>
```

//Now in your adapter inside `onBindViewHolder()` use the following code.

```
holder.buttonViewOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //creating a popup menu
                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mCtx, holder.buttonViewOption);
                //inflating menu from xml resource
                popup.inflate(R.menu.mycontextmenu);
                //adding click listener
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.menu1:
                                //handle menu1 click
                                break;
                            case R.id.menu2:
                                //handle menu2 click
                                break;
                            case R.id.menu3:
                                //handle menu3 click
                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                //displaying the popup
                popup.show();

            }
        });
```

Comment: if I use that how to edit the `addOnItemTouchListener` because I use that

Comment: You have to add the above code in Adapter class. What you can do is add an icon to adapter layout and set onclick listener to that icon inside onBindViewHolder()

Comment: I'm trying.. what data types for `mRecyclerView`? and cannot resolve symbol `one` until `four` in case

Comment: mCtx is the context. For buttonViewOption , did you add an ImageButton to the adapter layout?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138730/discussion-between-suhayl-sh-and-eggy-sudianto).

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** In Your MainActivityClass.java

```
private RecyclerView recyclerSavedHotel;

private ArrayList<Integer> totalHotel;
private ArrayList<String> nameCity;

TextView tvNoSavedHotel;
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

private static final String TAG = "SavedHotelClass";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    nameCity = new ArrayList();
    totalHotel = new ArrayList();

    nameCity.add("Ahmedabad");
    nameCity.add("Bhavnagar");

    nameCity.add("Mahuva");
    nameCity.add("Pune");

    nameCity.add("Bhavnagar");
    nameCity.add("Bhopal");

    nameCity.add("Rojkot");
    nameCity.add("Mahuva");

    nameCity.add("Agra");
    nameCity.add("Vadodra");

    totalHotel.add(1);
    totalHotel.add(2);

    totalHotel.add(4);
    totalHotel.add(6);

    totalHotel.add(8);
    totalHotel.add(20);

    totalHotel.add(11);
    totalHotel.add(23);

    totalHotel.add(21);
    totalHotel.add(3);

    if (nameCity.isEmpty() || totalHotel.isEmpty()) {
        tvNoSavedHotel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    initContext();
}

private void initContext() {
    recyclerSavedHotel = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_save_hotel);
    recyclerSavedHotel.setHasFixedSize(true);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerSavedHotel.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(nameCity, totalHotel);
    recyclerSavedHotel.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

Step 2: RecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
private ArrayList<String> nameCity;
private ArrayList<Integer> totalHotel;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<String> nameCity, ArrayList<Integer> totalHotel) {
    this.nameCity = nameCity;
    this.totalHotel = totalHotel;

}

@Override
public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate
            (R.layout.layout_saved_hotel, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);


}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.tvCityname.setText(nameCity.get(position));
    holder.tvTotalHotel.setText(totalHotel.get(position).toString());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return nameCity.size();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener {
    TextView tvCityname, tvTotalHotel;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvCityname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_saved_hotel_city_name);
        tvTotalHotel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_total_saved_hotel);
        itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Select The Action");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Call");//groupId, itemId, order, title
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "SMS");
    }
}
```

***layout_saved_hotel***

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/cardview_saved_hotel"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorWhite">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_saved_hotel_city_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_heart_red" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_total_saved_hotel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hotel saved" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_next_black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

***MainActivity***

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview_save_hotel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```